# Issues when suspending and waking up on desktop PC (20.04)

Tags: 20.04, suspend, power-management, wakeup

This PC is about a year old, and up until now I've had zero major issues with it. But since yesterday it has not been suspending properly. The keyboard and mouse lights shut off, but after a few seconds they turn back on and stay on (monitor stays off). The CPU fan RGB stays on, whereas normally that turns off, and the fan spins up noticeably louder than idle, and stays loud while in the suspended state.

The troubling part is that I can't wake it back up, either with the mouse, keyboard, or power button. I have to fully power it down and then back on by holding the power button, so I lose any unsaved work. Restart and shutdown both work normally. All of the above happens regardless of how I try to suspend it: power tab in the upper RH corner, let it sit long enough to suspend on its own, or `systemctl suspend`.

Software should all be up-to-date; there's nothing obvious to me that I might have done to trigger these issues (but I'm definitely not a Linux expert). Any insight into what might be causing this or how I can troubleshoot is very much appreciated!

Specs:
Ubuntu 20.04
CPU: AMD Ryzen 7 3700x
CPU fan: Cooler Master Hyper 212 RGB
motherboard: MSI MPG x570 Gaming Plus
memory: G.SKILL Trident Z Neo (2x16GB)
GPU: AMD Radeon rx 5700 xt
case: NZXT h510i

Answer (score 0):

Try [upgrading your kernel](https://itsfoss.com/upgrade-linux-kernel-ubuntu/).

I have a similar AMD setup and had the exact same problem as you described. Tried things like upgrading AMD drivers and my grub file, but none of them worked.

Upgraded the kernel from 5.13.19 to 5.14.0, rebooted and suspend immediately works as expected.

To check your current kernel version:

```
uname -r
```

To upgrade your kernel:

1. Select the version of your choice: [https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/?C=N;O=D](https://kernel.ubuntu.com/%7Ekernel-ppa/mainline/?C=N;O=D)
2. Go to `amd64/` and download all the `*-generic*.deb` packages
3. Move the packages to a new folder and run `sudo dpkg -i *.deb`